# Discard channels when recording from audio interface with FFmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audio-recording, recording

I'm calling `ffmpeg` from a program I'm writing in order to record audio from an audio interface. The audio interface has six channels and what I'd like to do is only record from the first two audio channels, discarding the rest. I can't work out how to do this or if it is even possible from the documentation.

The command I'm using is as follows:

`ffmpeg -f alsa -acodec pcm_s32le -ac 6 -ar 44100 -i hw:CARD=K6,DEV=0 output.wav`

Is this something that is possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -acodec pcm_s32le -ac 6 -ar 44100 -i hw:CARD=K6,DEV=0 
       -af "pan=2c|c0=c0|c1=c1" output.wav
```

The first argument to the pan filter is the number of output channels. Then come the individual channel mixes. Here it is first out channel is first in channel, and a similar assignment for the second.